# How call Connection Properties window in my C# application and use it?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ado.net, connection-string

[image]

Hi All

I want call **Connection Properties** window in C# application by a button and use Connection Information and it data in my application (ADO.NET or EntityFramework)

How I can use it ?
Is there any reference ?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see https://www.nuget.org/packages/DataConnectionDialog/
install via PM or use Nuget Packet Manager UI

`PM> Install-Package DataConnectionDialog`

1 of many Demo projects here [Connection proj Demo](http://erikej.blogspot.com.au/2010/04/using-adonet-data-connection-dialog-in.html)